# reciprocal of the Schwarz theorem

Tags: partial-derivative, examples-counterexamples

May you help me with a counterexample of the reciprocal of the Schwarz theorem? i.e. a  $\mathbb R^2$-function $f$ verifying $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} (a) = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x} (a) $ for all $a$ in the domain of $f$ but $f$ not being a $C^2$-function.
Kind regards and thank you